# Australian tourist visa for Philippine citizens - no stamp in the passport

Tags: visas, australia, filipino-citizens, passport-stamps

I have a Philippine passport and have an Australian tourist visa issued, but I do not have a stamp in my passport.  I am leaving tonight.  Will I be ok to travel without the stamp in the passport?

Comment: I got my Visa granted already. Cause worry me is it ok  i dont have a stamp on my Passport? Cause i'm leaving tonight going to Australia

Comment: click the Edit button and fix your question!

Comment: Isn't the visa stamped at the entry in the country? or are we talking about another kind of stamp? (I supposed your travel is to enter Australia)

Comment: @Vince, the Pinoy require an advanced visa for just about every country in the world. They can't depart on a flight without it. It's only for 'wealthy' nations where they stamp your passport upon arrival.

Answer (score 3):

You do not necessarily need a gummed sticker in your passport to travel to Australia.  The letter will normally be sufficient.

Airlines that have authorization to land passengers in Australia are required to have a computer connection to Australia's immigration authorities.  Before you board the airline, they will log in and receive a verification.  If you have a visa, the computer will indicate such and you will be permitted to board.

If you flag up as not having a valid visa, the airline will not allow you to board.  In that case you have been scammed and should contact your police.